# Understanding the architecture of neural networks

Tags: neural-network

I would like to understand something basic about neural networks. In input, are the observations that compose (X1, X2 ... Xn) or are they the variables? In this case, in Input if they are the variables, how do we represent the observations? Should we have as many hidden neurons as Output? For 3 output? can we put 10 neurons in the hidden layers?[Neural network architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJfRW.jpg)

Comment: "observation" is a term used for hidden Markov model, I don't think it is suitable here. It's just an input vector for which you would like to predict a value (or values). Depending on the task, the number and structure of hidden layers may be different

Comment: I meant sample when I said observations.